# Representing of natural number

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a given natural number with $n>1$, please prove that each natural $x>=2n$ can be represented as 
 $$x=a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_n^n-(b_1^n+\cdots+b_{n-1}^n)$$ 
where $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_{n-1}$ are non-negative integers and $a_1<x$, $a_2<x$, $\ldots,$ $a_n<x$, $b_1<x$, $\ldots,$ $b_{n-1}<x$

Comment: I bet if you solve the problem for $n=2$, then $n=3$, and maybe $n=4$, a pattern will appear.

Comment: @Hurkyl , fon n=2 solution is very simple :  $2x+1=(x+1)^2-x^2$ and $2x+2=(x+1)^2-x^2+1$ , but for n=3 I have no idea

Comment: @Andrew: For $n=3$ I went with $(x+1)^3+(x-1)^2-2x^3=6x$ and the fact that $n^3\equiv n\pmod6$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen , I've got this too . But how you formula only for 6|x (There are should be solution for all numbers)

Comment: @Andrew: Only used two positive cubes up to that point. $6x+1$, $6x+8$, $6x+27$, $6x+64$, $6x+125$ (if $x<0$, then $-x>0$).

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen  , you are right . But can you  get 11 for example?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen , x should be >0

Comment: The idea was that $11=125+(-114)=125+6\cdot(-19)$, so we would use $x=-19$. First write
$-114=(-18)^3+(-20)^2-2(-19)^3=19^3+19^3-18^3-20^3.$ Thus
$$11=5^3+19^3+19^3-18^3-20^3.$$
So $x$ can be negative if the $a_i$s and $b_i$s switch roles, @Andrew. Now in the morning light I do realize that I ignored the constraint $a_i,b_i<11$, so this doesn't work as simply as this.